# How to package all assets (image textures mainly) into a folder (not into .blend file)?

Tags: texturing, export, packing

I have a model that I need to send to other people and I'd like to make a package with the blend file and all the textures. I need people to be able to easily access the image textures without necesserally going into the blend file, so I want to put everything into the same folder and then I'll package everything into a zip and send. The textures are currently in a few different locations in my drive. I could manually copy all the textures to the same folder but there are a few dozen textures and I would have to double check to make sure I didn't miss any, so it would be really helpful if it could be done automatically.

However I can only find the option to package everything into a single blend file and no option to create a package with separate files.

For those familiar with 3ds Max, I'm looking for something that does exactly what the "archive" option does in Max. Or the "Collect Files" option in After Effects. Literally collect (and automatically relink) all assets into the same folder.

Comment: Hello :). You could pack all files into .Blend and then upack. They'll all end up in one new folder.

Comment: That seems to be a good workaround, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Make all Path relative" under File > External Data > Make all Path realitve and then you can move the complete folder to another place.

As far as i know, the closes to collect file is Pack Blend File, make all path relative will let you move your files to (for example) another computer